# Direction for Implementing EntityCollection task

Tags: java, c#, algorithm

I have the following task:

> Guidelines: You may implement your solution in Java/C#.
>
> 1. You are asked to implement the EntityCollection interface which is specified in the attached Java file.
> 2. Your implementation should support the following operations:
>      a. Add - adds the entity which is given as input to the collection.
>      b. Remove Max Value - removes the entity with the maximal value from the
>      collection and returns it.
> 3. You should provide 3 implementations for the following use-cases (A-C), according to the frequencies of performing Add & Remove Max
>      Value in these use-cases:
>
>    [image]
>
> Each use-case implementation should be optimized in terms of its WC
>   time complexity -
>
> - If one operation is more frequent than the other operation (e.g. high vs. low) – then the frequent operation should have the lowest
>     possible complexity, whereas the other operation may have higher
>     complexity but still optimized as much as possible.
> - If both operations are equally frequent (e.g. medium vs. medium) – then both should have similar complexity, which is as low as possible
>     in each operation while taking into account also the need for the same
>     complexity in the other operation.
>
> The given java code:
>
> ```
> public interface Entity
> {
>   public int getValue();  // unique
> }
>
> public interface EntityCollection
> {
>   public void add(Entity entity);
>   public Entity removeMaxValue();
> }
> ```
>
> Notes: You may use any existing collections/data structures in your
>   solution.

My question: Do you think that this assignment is clear enough? I feel a bit fugue about how to approach this.

I think that they asked me to write some collection. but I can't see what's the meaning of the use case/operation.

Any directions hints/code examples would be appreciated.

Comment: I understand how it might be confusing when newcomer read it but essentially it's asking you to dive into collection and way to add and remove item more efficiently depending on the amount of add and remove that will be thrown at it. Some type of algorithm will be faster than others at adding many item but slower to add few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The importance of this assignment is in your understanding of data structures and algorithms.

Doing a lot of adding and not a lot of removing the max value? use a linked-list. linked-list is O(1) for adding a new value to the list. so use that and use an easy to implement search algorithm for your second operation since it isn't used much.

For the second use case, you need to balance the speed of both operations, so choose a data structure that has decent speed for both. Maybe a Binary Search Tree.

And so on for the final case.

Here is a nice link outlining data structures and their speeds [Cheat Sheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)

You could choose a Hashtable for some of these, but note that despite the hash tables speed, it consumes extreme amounts of memory to achieve it. However, that is only a concern if memory is a problem or you are working with large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you need to look into the data structures which efficiently support the add or remove operations as per the use case and then internally make use of corresponding in-built data structure in language of your choice and if you want more flexibility then implement that data structure yourself.

For example in use case A the add frequency is high and remove max value freq. is low, so you may make use of a Data structure which supports addition in say `O(1)`(constant-time) time-complexity. Whereas, for remove you may make use of something which is `O(n)`(linear-time) time complexity or anything less than `O(n^2)` is good enough for low-frequency operations.

So for use case A you can make use of Linked List as addition is `O(1)` but for remove-max you need to sort and then remove the max, which makes `O(nlogn)` complexity.

For Use case C - you can choose to go with Priority queue which has `O(1)` for remove max and `O(log n)` for addition. Priority queue is internally max-heap implementation in Java.